# In Ubuntu command ls -l with jc of kellyjonbrazil dosn´t work correct

Tags: json, linux, parsing, json.net, ls

I try to convert the ls -l command with jc (from [js](https://kellyjonbrazil.github.io/jc/docs/parsers/ls)) in a json-object.

```
ls -l | jc --ls -p
```

Unfortunate I get this output:

[image: wrong output]

But according to docs from Developer ([docs](https://kellyjonbrazil.github.io/jc/docs/parsers/ls_s) the output must be something líke that.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin | jc --ls -p -r
[
  {
    "filename": "apropos",
    "link_to": "whatis",
    "flags": "lrwxrwxrwx.",
    "links": "1",
    "owner": "root",
    "group": "root",
    "size": "6",
    "date": "Aug 15 10:53"
  },
  {
    "filename": "arch",
    "flags": "-rwxr-xr-x.",
    "links": "1",
    "owner": "root",
    "group": "root",
    "size": "33080",
    "date": "Aug 19 23:25"
  },
  ...
]
```

I exoected this output with this command:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin | jc --ls -p -r

[
  {
    "filename": "apropos",
    "link_to": "whatis",
    "flags": "lrwxrwxrwx.",
    "links": "1",
    "owner": "root",
    "group": "root",
    "size": "6",
    "date": "Aug 15 10:53"
  },
  {
    "filename": "arch",
    "flags": "-rwxr-xr-x.",
    "links": "1",
    "owner": "root",
    "group": "root",
    "size": "33080",
    "date": "Aug 19 23:25"
  },
  ...
]
```

Have anybody a idea or experience?

I thank you in advance

Andrej

Comment: Does it work if you turn off the localization? `LC_ALL=C ls -l`

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the tool only handles non-localised output of `ls`. Try running it with the C locale:

```
LC_ALL=C ls - l | jc --ls -p
```